# Placing \section, \subsection in the right margin of an RTL document

Tags: sectioning, margins, polyglossia, right-to-left

Rather than the default placing of `\section` and `\subsection` on their own line, I'd like to place them on the right margin (in a Right To Left document).

My current usage looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew, numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}

\begin{document}
\section{}
  \subsection*{א}
    אבג
  \subsection*{ב}
    דהו
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Instead, I want to achieve this:

[image]

It is not exactly clear in the image but the bold text should be on the right margin.

Ideally I would like each `\subsection` to also include the current `\section` when it's printed, but if there is a `\section` without any `\subsection`s, then only the `\section` should be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titlesec` package is brilliant for doing all sorts of fancy headings. It plays well with `bidi` provided that you load `titlesec` first (so in this case that means before `polyglossia`). So a partial answer is

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew, numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{New Peninim MT} % I don't have David!

\titleformat{\subsection}[leftmargin]{\bfseries}{\thesection}%
  {0.6em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{2em}{0.5ex}{1em}
```

which, when used with non-starred `subsection`s, gives

[image: Sample Hebrew titles]

Some notes:

1. For RTL documents `leftmargin` means, er, the right margin.
2. This relies on your decision to include subsection *numbers* manually as subsection *titles*. I attempted to provide a solution which avoids this but discovered, as you may have, that `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\hebrewnumeral{\arabic{subsection}}}` causes an error for no immediately apparent reason... so I guess all I can point out is that you will have to adjust manually if you rearrange your subsections.
3. The final part of your question (if I understand it correctly - you want to suppress a separate section number unless there are no subsections to display it?) is more difficult, for the reason that LaTeX doesn't know when it typesets a `section` title whether or not it will contain any `subsection`s. So you will need to use information written to the auxiliary files on previous compilation runs. I can't see a straightforward way of using the information already written to the `.aux` file - although it's certainly there - so you might need to write this information out yourself and then read it back in on the next run when deciding whether or not to set the `section` number. Sorry if this all sounds very complicated - it's really more fiddly than difficult. I don't have time to implement a solution along these lines myself at the moment but will try to return to this answer in the next few days if none has appeared by then!

---

**Addendum**

If you're happy to get rid of the section number in general (*i.e.*, ignoring the possibility of a section without subsections), then `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}` and use `\arabic{section}` instead of `\thesection` in the `\titleformat{\subsection}` command. You probably also want to get rid of the extra space left for the section number and title using `\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}`.

In fact, now I come to think of it, if you're willing to manually mark any sections without footnotes, you could make this approach work by defining a command, `\varsection` say, to set `\thesection` and the spacing, typeset the section title, and then reset as above.

Comment: Awesome! This is very close to what I want. The `\renewcommand` actually did work for me. I also changed the titleformat to include `\thesection` to get the current section right next to the subsection in the right margin. I have one problem left: `\section` still shows the current section (in your picture, the single `1` at the top). Is there a way to omit it while keeping the counter itself? (so `\thesection` keeps on showing in the right margin)

Comment: If you're willing to get rid of section titles entirely, or at least mark the places you want them to appear, the addendum above might help?

Comment: I will try this sometime in the future. For now I got rid of subsections entirely and I'm manually typing the section titles, i.e. `\section*{1}, \section*{2 א}, \section*{2 ב}`. It's slightly more work, but it does the trick ;)